# Does Node.js have a process.pid equivalent to identify the current promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Debugging promises in Node can be difficult, requiring wrapping promise code.  One utility that would help would something like:

node.util.promiseId() : return an id for the for current promise being executed.

So that I could:

```
function bar() {
    // return some common computation part
    console.log('working on promise', node.util.promiseId());

function foo(result) {
    // promise analyzed results from some complicated way.
    bar();
    ...
}

fetch().then(foo)...
```

Is there anything close for ES6 promises?

To clarify:   I currently use an interceptor when debugging promises, so my debug output can look like this:

```
prolog:  new A1 chain
prolog:  (A1).then new A2
prolog:  (A2).then new A3
prolog:  (A3).then new A4
prolog:  new B5 chain from argument
prolog:  (B5).then new B6
prolog:  A2 fulfills
prolog:  A3 fulfills
prolog:  A4 fulfills
prolog:  B6 fulfills
```

Being able to identify which promise is causing code to be executed would go a long way to identifying unusual race conditions and resource conflicts.

Comment: What do you mean by `promiseId` ? Can you give an example? There are no promises in your code. Are you talking about the promise returned by `fetch()` ?

Comment: What would such an id be useful for?

Comment: There is no single "current promise being executed".  Promises are just event/callback managers for keeping track of async operations.  There can be hundreds of live/unresolved promises at any given moment.

Comment: There are many live/unresolved promises at a given moment.  At the point a given point of code is executing, it is executing because of one of those operations.   The question is, which one?

Comment: The only time you'd need that is with `Promise.race`. All other codepaths are deterministic.

Comment: Sorry jib, that is not completely true.  Consider simultaneous waits on unreliable IO and then waiting on contention for a unique external resource.  I run it twice and get two different outcomes.